# PHP - split arrays if value 2 is higher than 1 (

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have worked hard this night to figure out how to split my arrays into a lot of arrays, defined by a value in the array

I could have this value

```
$array = array ( 
    array ("Apple", 10),
    array("Ball", 5) 
);
```

Then I want Apple to have 10 arrays where the value is "Apple", and Ball to have 5 arrays where the value is "Ball"

Then I came up with this, but the output seems pretty strange..

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $val):
    for($i = 1; $i <= $val[1]; $i++):
        $newarray[$i] = $val[0];
    endfor;
endforeach;

print_r($newarray);
// Array ( [0] => Ball [1] => Ball [2] => Ball [3] => Ball [4] => Ball [5] => Ball [6] => Apple [7] => Apple [8] => Apple [9] => Apple [10] => Apple )
```

Hope you guys understand my question, and hope some one can figure it out.

In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php) can help here:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $sub) {
  $result[] = array_fill(0, $sub[1], $sub[0]);
}

print_r($result);
```

See it here in action: http://viper-7.com/MhnWFt

Comment: Perfect! But I didn't want a multidimensionel array by this. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is cool and short. Great way around. I didn't think by myself at my above comment,  but got it working. :) Great, thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the purpose is to create an array with 10 "Apples" and another one with 5 "Balls"

```
$array = array ( 
    array ("Apple", 10),
    array("Ball", 5) 
);
$newarray = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $tmparray = null;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $val[1]; $i++){
        $tmparray[$i] = $val[0];
    }
    $newarray[] = $tmparray;
}
print_r($newarray);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => Apple
            [2] => Apple
            [3] => Apple
            [4] => Apple
            [5] => Apple
            [6] => Apple
            [7] => Apple
            [8] => Apple
            [9] => Apple
            [10] => Apple
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Ball
            [2] => Ball
            [3] => Ball
            [4] => Ball
            [5] => Ball
        )

)
```